# Cannot add a right or left bar button item to my nav controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Have tried all the examples on this website I just don't see anything on my modal view, I do see the navigationbar though but its empty

```
EditEntityViewController *editEntityViewController = [[EditEntityViewController alloc] init];
editEntityViewController.currentNode = newNode;
editEntityViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editEntityViewController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;


UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];          
editEntityViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release];


[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[editEntityViewController release];
```

Comment: It's a bit odd to have a navigation controller in a modal view. Have you tried using a UINavigationBar in your editEntityViewController instead and adding your button to that?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't create the same effect as what I am trying to do

Comment: It is not odd to have a navigation controller in a modal view. It's the standard way to add a navigation bar to a modal sheet. What TheLearner is doing is perfectly acceptable and I can't see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, your code was correct and is the standard way to show a popup sheet with a UINavigationBar to hold buttons to dismiss the sheet. However, you had defined an IBOutlet in EditViewController called navigationItem, which was causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the rightBarButtonItem on editEntityViewController **before** you create the UINavigationController with initWithRootViewController:.

I think that the navigation bar is set up when the UINavigationController is created. Adding the right bar item after creation time is too late.

EDIT: Ok, so that's not the issue.

The following minimal code snippet works so I would check whether your EditEntityViewController is doing something to remove the button elsewhere:

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *popupController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popupController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;


    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                     target:self
                                                                     action:nil];       

    popupController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
    [anotherButton release];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [popupController release];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I also think its perfectly normal to do this.  What I want to do is display the modal and then push views ontop when selecting different things

Comment: Ok - see the minimal code sample above. Something somewhere else is causing the problem. The code you posted should work.

Comment: See my answer, feel free to answer the question aswell

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this was not working is really stupid.  Basically I had an IBOutlet defined in EditViewController called navigationItem which was conflicting with the SDK's property with the same name.

I removed it and the link from the nib and as Robin says it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Modally presented view controllers on navigation controllers don't have navigationItem nor navigationController properties. They DO, however, have parentViewController property, but this is irrelevant in your case.

If you want to customize navigation bar on your modally presented view, you should connect `IBOutlet` from view controller managing that view to the navigation bar placed in that managed view. Then do the manipulation through `IBOutlet` instance variable.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your sentence I don't understand you

Comment: Okay I understand after reading it several times.  What you are basically saying is I cannot use a navigation controller :)

Comment: You can use navigation controller, but navigation bar won't be tied to navigation item provided by said navigation controller.

Comment: Eimantas is incorrect. Showing a UINavigationController modally as a way of adding a navigation bar to a modal sheet is a very common thing to do. Take a look at the [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) sample, for instance. The 'add new recipe' interface is being created just like TheLearner is doing.

Comment: @RobinSummerhill - you're right. I misread the code sample that he wants to show the view controller over the navigation controller. Still, create whole navController only to get the navigation bar is a bit of overhead IMHO.